# After suspend guest OS hangs when using vagrant with nfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

Host OS Ubuntu 15.10
Guest OS Ubuntu 14.10

Using Vagrant with nfs and Virtualbox and static ip on the private network.

It is working perfectly except that after having suspended the host OS, the entire guest OS will be unusable.
This does not happen when using the normal virtualbox shared folders.

It's not only the nfs shared folder that is unusable, the entire OS is hanging.
Even `syslog` does not seem to see much action.
This is `syslog` on the guest, from waking up until `vagrant halt` is completed.

```
Feb 26 07:15:33 vagrant kernel: [ 8375.252989] e1000: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
Feb 26 07:16:11 vagrant kernel: [ 8413.109832] nfs: server 192.168.33.1 not responding, still trying
Feb 26 07:16:38 vagrant kernel: [ 8440.687476] nfs: server 192.168.33.1 not responding, still trying
Feb 26 07:17:01 vagrant CRON[3776]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 26 07:20:33 vagrant rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="753" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

How can this be fixed?
How should I debug it?

Comment: I have the same problem, when Ubuntu wakes up from suspend, a before running vagrant is messed up. Servers running in vagrant are not reachable anymore.